# ActiveRecord won't find superclass records until you search for a subclass

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm developing a Rails application where I use single table inheritance. There's an `ActiveRecord` model, `User`, which has a subclass `Attendee`. The latter has two subclasses, `Host` and `Guest`. Let's say that I'd like to find the attendees, both guests and hosts. The query would be as simple as this:

```
Attendee.all
```

However, this is not retrieving any result. Taking a look at the SQL generated:

```
SELECT "attendees".* FROM "attendees" WHERE "attendees"."type" IN ('Attendee')
```

It doesn't find any result, because all the records are stored using either `Guest` or `Host` classes, so there won't be any record with the type `Attendee`.
Right after, I look for all the guests using `Guest.all`, and it does retrieve records. If I look for attendees again, the SQL query changes to:

```
SELECT "attendees".* FROM "attendees" WHERE "attendees"."type" IN ('Attendee', 'Guest')
```

So it seems that Rails doesn't mind about subclasses until you use them. Do you know the reason of this behavior and how to correct it?

Comment: Do you have any scopes set up?  I ask because I've just checked an STI site I have and doing `Model.all` on the parent just generates `SELECT "models.*" FROM "models"`

Comment: Actually the application is a bit more complex, `Attendee` is a subclass of an `ActiveRecord` class. So it'd be `User` > `Attendee` > `Guest`. I'm gonna edit the question